# How to export a DataTable to Xml with ALL columns as attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, datatable

Question: I'm exporting a System.Data.DataTable to XML.
So far it works fine.
But I want to have all the data in attributes, which works fine as well.
But my problem now, if in one column, all rows are NULL, no empty attributes are written.
So if I read the XML back to a DataTable, it lacks this column...

How can I force write all columns even when they are empty ?
(DataType not necessarely string)

```
public void ExportTable(string strDirectory, DataTable dtt)
{
    using (System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet()) {
        string strTable = dtt.TableName;

        ds.Tables.Add(dtt);
        ds.DataSetName = strTable;

        // Move data to attributes 
        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables) {

            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns) {
                dc.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
            }

        }

        System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings settings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        //settings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1") 
        settings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        settings.CloseOutput = true;
        settings.CheckCharacters = true;
        settings.NewLineChars = "\r\n";
        // vbCr & vbLf 

        // Write as UTF-8 with indentation 
        using (System.Xml.XmlWriter w = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(System.IO.Path.Combine(strDirectory, strTable + ".xml"), settings)) {

            // Strip out timezone 
            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables) {

                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns) {

                    if (object.ReferenceEquals(dc.DataType, typeof(DateTime))) {
                        dc.DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Unspecified;
                    }

                }

            }

            ds.Tables[0].WriteXml(w, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
            w.Flush();
            w.Close();
        }
        // w 

    }
    // ds 

}
// ExportTable
```

VB.NET original:

```
 Public Sub ExportTable(strDirectory As String, dtt As DataTable)
        Using ds As New System.Data.DataSet()
            Dim strTable As String = dtt.TableName

            ds.Tables.Add(dtt)
            ds.DataSetName = strTable

            ' Move data to attributes
            For Each dt As DataTable In ds.Tables

                For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                    dc.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute
                Next dc

            Next dt

            Dim settings As New System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings()
            settings.Indent = True
            'settings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
            settings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
            settings.CloseOutput = True
            settings.CheckCharacters = True
            settings.NewLineChars = vbCrLf ' vbCr & vbLf

            ' Write as UTF-8 with indentation
            Using w As System.Xml.XmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(System.IO.Path.Combine(strDirectory, strTable & ".xml"), settings)

                ' Strip out timezone
                For Each dt As DataTable In ds.Tables

                    For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns

                        If dc.DataType Is GetType(DateTime) Then
                            dc.DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Unspecified
                        End If

                    Next dc

                Next dt

                ds.Tables(0).WriteXml(w, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)
                w.Flush()
                w.Close()
            End Using ' w

        End Using ' ds

    End Sub ' ExportTable
```

Comment: Use XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema. With a schema included it won't matter that it doesn't add attributes for null values.

Comment: @JamieSee: Without schema would be nicer, because the result should be easy to read in any programming language, not just .NET.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every XML attribute must be assigned a value that is enclosed in a pair of single or double quotation marks. There is no equivalent in plain text to denote a NULL value. A pair of quotation marks with no value to represent an empty string is not the same as a NULL value. Therefore, the only way to represent a NULL attribute is to omit the attribute.

This means that you will need to either set `AllowDBNull` to false and assign a suitable `DefaultValue` on the DataColumn, or include the schema.

Also, see [Handling Null Values (ADO.NET).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172138.aspx), particularly this section which explains the behavior:

> In addition, the following rules apply for an instance of
>   DataRow.["columnName"] null assignments:
>
> 1.The default default value is DbNull.Value for all except the strongly typed null columns where it is the appropriate strongly typed
>   null value.
>
> 2.Null values are never written out during serialization to XML files (as in "xsi:nil").
>
> 3.All non-null values, including defaults, are always written out while serializing to XML. This is unlike XSD/XML semantics where a
>   null value (xsi:nil) is explicit and the default value is implicit (if
>   not present in XML, a validating parser can get it from an associated
>   XSD schema). The opposite is true for a DataTable: a null value is
>   implicit and the default value is explicit.
>
> 4.All missing column values for rows read from XML input are assigned NULL. Rows created using NewRow or similar methods are assigned the
>   DataColumn's default value.
>
> 5.The IsNull method returns true for both DbNull.Value and INullable.Null.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the column [DefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.defaultvalue.aspx) to something valid

```
foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables) {

        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns) {
            dc.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
           //If type is DataType string
           dc.DefaultValue = String.Empty;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Two points:

First:
The ExportTable() threw an exception: "DataTable already belongs to another DataSet." When I executed:

```
ds.Tables.Add(dtt)
```

I corrected this by making a local copy of the table:

```
Dim dtX As DataTable = dtt.Copy
ds.Tables.Add(dtX)
ds.DataSetName = strTable
```

This worked well.

Second:
If you use the XML to create a dynamic SQL statement, there is no need to be concerned about the columns/fields with NULL value being omitted in the XML export. Simply walk through the a attributes that are in the XML record, build the INSERT or UPDATE statement and execute a connection command. This is faster than using a DataSet.

For INSERT it has one drawback. If the primary key is created by incrementing an identity column, an ADO.Net DataSet will return it. Dynamic SQL will require a SELECT statement to retrieve it.

Also, it would be good idea to obfuscate your code.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit old thread but, maybe it can help someone:
If you are not writing big xml files frequently (it's ok for exporting settings or something similar) you can use function below, otherwise it's better to use cutom xml schema.

```cs
private static void addEmptyElementsToXML(DataSet dataSet)
{
    foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataRow.ItemArray.Length; j++)
            {
                if (dataRow.ItemArray[j] == DBNull.Value)
                    dataRow.SetField(j, string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using(DataTable dTable = ..something..)
using(DataSet dS = new DataSet())
using(XmlTextWriter xmlStream = new XmlTextWriter("FILENAME.XML", Encoding.UTF8))
{
    //set xml to be formatted so it can be easily red by human
    xmlStream.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    xmlStream.Indentation = 4;

    //add table to dataset
    dS.Tables.Add(dTable);

    //call the mentioned function so it will set all DBNull values in dataset
    //to string.Empty
    addEmptyElementsToXML(dS);

    //write xml to file
    xmlStream.WriteStartDocument();
    dS.WriteXml(xmlStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching the whole world for a solution of writing null fields to XML using DataSet.WriteXML(). I found that following works in a performance optimized way. I have created a function for your convenience. Change your dataset tables one after the other by calling the following function and replacing the tables.

```
private DataTable GetNullFilledDataTableForXML(DataTable dtSource)
{
    // Create a target table with same structure as source and fields as strings
    // We can change the column datatype as long as there is no data loaded
    DataTable dtTarget = dtSource.Clone();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dtTarget.Columns)
        col.DataType = typeof(string);

    // Start importing the source into target by ItemArray copying which 
    // is found to be reasonably fast for null operations. VS 2015 is reporting
    // 500-525 milliseconds for loading 100,000 records x 10 columns 
    // after null conversion in every cell 
    // The speed may be usable in many circumstances.
    // Machine config: i5 2nd Gen, 8 GB RAM, Windows 7 64bit, VS 2015 Update 1
    int colCountInTarget = dtTarget.Columns.Count;
    foreach (DataRow sourceRow in dtSource.Rows)
    {
        // Get a new row loaded with data from source row
        DataRow targetRow = dtTarget.NewRow();
        targetRow.ItemArray = sourceRow.ItemArray;

        // Update DBNull.Values to empty string in the new (target) row
        // We can safely assign empty string since the target table columns
        // are all of string type
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < colCountInTarget; ctr++)
            if (targetRow[ctr] == DBNull.Value)
                targetRow[ctr] = String.Empty;

        // Now add the null filled row to target datatable
        dtTarget.Rows.Add(targetRow);
    }

    // Return the target datatable
    return dtTarget;
}
```