# Dataset add new empty row

Tags: c#, dataset, row

I have a `dataset` with 59 columns. I want to add a new row where I only know at the moment the first entry. I know I can add the row with

`mydataset.Tables[0].Rows.Add("Firstentry",,,,and so on for empty columns);`

Is there an easier way so that I don't have to write 58 commas for the 58 empty colums in my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// create new row
var newR = mydataset.Tables[0].NewRow();
// set 1 value
newR[0] = "Firstentry";
// add to table
mydataset.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newR);
```

check [NewRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation

Comment: @katz, i researched this issue with XML a bit and found this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231621/how-to-export-a-datatable-to-xml-with-all-columns-as-attributes; the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10232689/1506454 section#4, explains it i think

Comment: Thanks again, meanwhile I solved the problem with adding `""` to the empty columns: `for (int i = 1; i < 59; i++)
                    {
                        newR[i] = "";
                    }`

Comment: @katz, i thought of it: easy fix unless you have dataColumns with non-`string` data type  (`int`,`datetime`, etc); also possible set DefaultValue for each DataColumn in table