# dataTable.WriteXml() is not creating tags for the column that have NULL in them

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datatable

I have a dataTable which have some columns that are NULL, and when I tried the following, it simply skipped those columns and created xml:

```
dataTable.WriteXml(filelocation);
```

Comment: check this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231621/how-to-export-a-datatable-to-xml-with-all-columns-as-attributes

Comment: Yep...that's the way it works.

Comment: Thanks! I used string.Empty now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i have read about

> ```
> > WriteXml(filelocation)
> ```

, i found that cells which are "null" in the "Datatable" don't get written as xml or their xml tags are not generated.
Thus to resolve this issue i used

> string.Empty

where i was using null while initializing. This resolved my issue.