# How to serialize a datatable in a way similar to the raw mode provided by T-SQL FOR XML clause?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, t-sql

T-SQL has a [`FOR XML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/xml/basic-syntax-of-the-for-xml-clause?view=sql-server-ver16) clause that allows XML serialization from a rowset. This clause has a mode named as `RAW` which serializes every row using an xml element and serialize its column values as element attribute values. For example, a rowset like the one below:

```
Column_1 Column_2
-------- --------
one      1
two      2
```

when serialized using raw mode gets serialized as follows:

```
<row Column_1="one" Column_2="1" />
<row Column_1="two" Column_2="2" />
```

This serialization mode is light and useful when column data uses basic types, because it is a less  verbose than `PATH` mode which serializes every column value using a xml element (requiring  its open and close tags)

When a rowset from a [`System.Data.DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.7.2) instance is serialized from C# using
[`WriteXml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.writexml?view=netframework-4.7.2) methods it gets serialized as described for the `PATH` mode of the T-SQL [`FOR XML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/xml/basic-syntax-of-the-for-xml-clause?view=sql-server-ver16) select clause. For the previous example it will result in something like

```
<DataSet>
    <row><Column_1>one</Column_1><Column_2>1</Column_2></row>
    <row><Column_1>two</Column_1><Column_2>2</Column_2></row>
</DataSet>
```

My question: is there a C# native way to serialize a `System.DataTable` instance in the same way that `SELECT FOR XML RAW(<element_name>)` does?

Comment: use FOR JSON AUTO;  and it is time to forget about xml, it was actual 30 years ago

Comment: @Serge Bad advice.   As much as I prefer JSON...  XML is still very much alive and I suspect it will be around for long time.

Comment: maybe something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231621/how-to-export-a-datatable-to-xml-with-all-columns-as-attributes

Comment: I wouldn't say xml has no uses, but serializing datable to xml,especially attribute-centric one seems a bit suspect to me, here json array would be definitely tighter, but what are you trying to do with the xml?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Yes, I am agree, for the big corporations. Some of them since are using Windows XP, to save money for software updates. But I don't think that I will ever work for them.

Comment: @Serge I have no idea what you are talking about.  Just for fun, Google "is xml dying"

Comment: @JohnCappelletti You are too yong to know what is Windows XP.  Just google it for fun.

Comment: @siggermannen the link you provided contains the answer. The only thing should be done is to set the `ColumnMapping` property to `MappingType.Attribute`

Comment: @siggemannen the reason to serialize in that attribute-centric mode is because there is a third-party a stored procedure behind the endpoint that expects data using this attribute-centric schema. The owner of that endpoint and stored procedure is another IT provider who refuses to edit that implementation adducing that this way puts less data on the wire and complies with xml, allowing then to use internally their already constructed objects to handle xml compliant data

Comment: @MauricioOrtega, glad it was useful, and yeah, sometimes you gotta work with inflexible xml providers!

Comment: @Serge, not every project or scenario is candidate for full refactoring, specially when many IT providers are involved the cost of full refactoring (measured in time, desing and IT providers agreements) sometimes is prohibitive; for that reason some projects require adaptation with an already alive system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @siggemanen comment linking to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231621/how-to-export-a-datatable-to-xml-with-all-columns-as-attributes) I learned that the right way to configure how a datatable is serialized when its native [WriteXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.writexml?view=netframework-4.7.2) methods are invoked is to set the [ColumnMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.columnmapping?view=netframework-4.7.2) property. In this case to map them as attributes the value is `MappingType.Attribute` This code shows the behavior

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Get a datatable with 3 columns and two rows for testing purpouses
        var dt = BuildDataTableWithData();


        //To prepare the datatable to serialize columns as xml attributes property ColumnMapping for every column must be set to MappingType.Attribute
        foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            dc.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;

        //Serializes and display result
        var serialized = Serialize(dt);
        Console.WriteLine(serialized);
    }
    
    private static DataTable BuildDataTableWithData() {
        var dt = new DataTable("table");
        (new DataSet("DataSet")).Tables.Add(dt);
        
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
            new DataColumn("Column_1", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Column_2", typeof(decimal)),
            new DataColumn("Column_3", typeof(DateTime))
        });
        
        dt.Rows.Add("one",1,DateTime.Now);
        dt.Rows.Add("two",1,DateTime.Now);
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        
        return dt;
    }
    
    static string Serialize(DataTable dt) {
        var enc = Encoding.ASCII;
        var mems = new MemoryStream();
        var xmlw = new XmlTextWriter(mems, enc);
                
        dt.WriteXml(xmlw, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
        
        var serialized = enc.GetString(mems.ToArray());
        return serialized;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, you can just use `XElement` and friends, along with LINQ.

```cs
var rootNode =
    new XElement(
        "DataSet",
        dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row =>
            new XElement(
                "row",
                dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(col =>
                    new XElement(col.ColumnName, row[col.Ordinal])
                )
            )
        )
    );

Console.WriteLine(rootNode.ToString());
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0CAXKl)

If you want to use attributes, just change `new XElement(col.ColumnName, ...` to

```cs
new XAttribute(col.ColumnName, row[col.Ordinal])
```